# Full command line in ps -o call

Tags: terminal, ps

On Ubuntu 20.04.3, calling `ps -e -o args,pid,etime,%cpu,%mem --forest | egrep "firefox|PID" | grep -v grep` gives me the following result:

```
COMMAND                         PID     ELAPSED %CPU %MEM
 \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefo    5730    01:58:40 20.8  4.9
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    5811    01:58:39  0.0  0.2
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    5841    01:58:39  0.1  0.7
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    5895    01:58:39  0.0  0.9
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    5926    01:58:39  4.3  2.0
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    6000    01:58:38 21.7  2.0
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    6094    01:58:32  4.2  0.3
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    7004    01:54:00  1.4  2.0
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    7648    01:37:06  0.8  1.9
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi    8351    01:31:35  1.0  1.0
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi   12159       45:04  3.5  2.3
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi   15712       03:56  2.0  0.9
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi   15833       03:25  1.4  0.9
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi   16878       02:39  0.0  0.4
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi   16924       02:30  0.0  0.4
 |   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/fi   16962       02:24  0.0  0.4
```

which is what I want except for the shortened command line. Adding `ww` to ps (`ps -eww`) does not change the output.
`ps auxww --forest | egrep "firefox|PID" | grep -v grep` works, but in BSD style and not with the columns I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To output the full command line, regardless of length, `args` needs to come last:

```
ps -e -o pid,etime,%cpu,%mem,args --forest
```

If you want to keep `args` first, you can specify an alternative header name with the width you want — but that will still truncate command lines which are longer than the header name:

```
ps -e -o args=args-----------------------------------------------------,pid,etime,%cpu,%mem --forest
```